# App do not run on iPhone 3G in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: xcode4, iphone-3g

I already know that issue related with armv6, and new "required device capabilities" plist entry.

Interestingly, I compiled and run fine in Xcode4.2 in exact settings. When I updated to 4.3.2,  I just can't run my app on iPhone 3G, but it fines newer versions of iPhone.

Here some screenshots from my project's settings;

Build Settings:

[image]

Executable Settings:

[image]

Plist file

[image]

Summary Page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your info.plist for "Required device capability". It should have "armv6" entry and not "armv7". XCode4's default is "armv7".